# Getting error while installing mongoDB : gpg key error

Tags: mongodb, installation

I am Trying install [mongoDB according to this link](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

and i am Getting error:

```
root@MrAK-desktop:~# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.IBN5O6rAAC --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.IBN5O6rAAC --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I am sure that my connection is having no Problem,

> apt-get update and upgrade

these commands are working,

Answer (score 3):

```
requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection timed out
```

The hkp protocol runs on port TCP 11371. Make sure the firewall allows access to that port on keyserver.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Thanks. For those poor people who are blocked by FW, you can try to open a ssh tunnel to bypass it (assuming you stil have access to port 22 and you can ssh to a host that is not blocked):
ssh -fNL 11371:keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371 user@my_unblocked_host
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 127.0.0.1 --recv 7F0CEB10

Answer (score 3):

Simply run `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10` to use port `80` and bypass your firewall (hopefully).

Comment: doesn't seem to be working for me (only ? :) i run a debian container in my docker host which seems to be blocked on port 11371 by the firewall. i still get a timeout :/